# Python selenium: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'followin' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Code block:

```py
class accinfo():
    def getfolowing(acclink):
        time.sleep(2)
        profileurl = "https://instagram.com/" + (acclink) + "/"
        browser.get(profileurl)
        time.sleep(2)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a/div'))).click()

        ##accinfo.scroldownflowng()
        following = []
        following = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'notranslate._0imsa')
        for followin in following:
            print(followin.text)
        print(len(followin))


time.sleep(10)
accinfo.goprofile(hedefhesap, loginfo1)
accinfo.getfollower(hedefhesap)
accinfo.getfolowing(hedefhesap)
```

I'm gettin error, how can I fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ayarb/PycharmProjects/instagrambotv1/main.py", line 112, in <module>
    accinfo.getfolowing(hedefhesap)
  File "C:/Users/ayarb/PycharmProjects/instagrambotv1/main.py", line 62, in getfolowing
    print(len(followin))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'followin' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to use local variable followin, that you create here:

```
for followin in following:
```

You better initialize variable before use it. Just add:

```
followin = null
```

at the beginning

P.S.

When you use loop `for` you create a local variable that exist only in loop. When you exit the loop, your variable `followin` just disappear.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'followin' referenced before assignment
```

...implies that you have referenced the variable **`followin`** even before it was assigned any value.

---

The *list* *`following`* is created with **0** elements i.e.

```
print(len(followin))
```

would print 0.

But even before that within the *`for()`* loop you have tried to iterate the list elements through the variable *`followin`* which never gets initialized. Hence you see the error.